Normalized prior for discretized random variable
I would like to confirm my understanding of deriving a prior from a discretized continuous random variable and the correct expression for the normalization condition of the prior, please advise if the following working is consistent and correct:
Consider that we have discretized a continuous random variable $\theta$ such that $\theta_1, \dotsc,\theta_d \in [0, \pi]$. We then have the posterior distribution given by Bayes rule
$$P(\theta_j|\mu) = \frac{P(\mu|\theta_j)P(\theta_j)}{P(\mu)},$$ where $\mu$ denotes the measurement outcome and $P(\mu)$ normalizes the posterior. The normalization of the posterior is then given by $\sum_{i}^{d}P(\theta_j|\mu)\delta \theta = 1$ where $\delta \theta = \theta_d/(d-1)$.
The marginal distribution of $\mu$ can be computed by summing over all possible values of $\theta_j$ yielding
$$P(\mu) = \sum_{j=1}^{d}P(\mu|\theta_j)P(\theta_j)\delta \theta.$$
We can also express the prior $P(\theta_j)$ as a marginal distribution
$$P(\theta_j) = \sum_{\mu}P(\theta_j|\mu)P(\mu),$$ thus yielding
$$P(\theta_j) = \sum_{\mu}P(\theta_j|\mu)\sum_{k=1}^{d}P(\mu|\theta_k)P(\theta_k)\delta \theta.$$
We would then expect that the normalization of the prior holds as $\sum_{j=1}^{d} P(\theta_j)=1$. Hence we do not need to include the factor $\delta \theta$ for the normalization of the prior as $\sum_{j=1}^{d} P(\theta_j) \delta \theta=1$. Is this correct?

"The normalization of the posterior is then given by $\sum_{i}^{d}P(\theta_j|\mu)\delta \theta = 1$ where $\delta \theta = \theta_d/(d-1)$." That's a mistake, I think. The correct property is: $\sum_{i}^{d}P(\theta_j|\mu) = 1$
.
